# How to get, return and delete a random element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How to get, return and delete a random element from an array and the most efficient to do this?
The array code would look something like this:

```
String arr[3] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse"};
```

Thanks for any help.

## Edit

By the way it's for a memory game, so if it repeats more than twice, I would ruin the game.

Comment: Do you need just to remove an element or a cell from the array and slide the array to left?

Comment: This seems to be HW or something like that. We can help you but you should show us what you have tried.

Comment: Generate A **random** index from `java.util.Random`, using `.nextInt()` and do whatever you want to do with it. Simple as that.

Comment: @QBrute For now I've just created the array and have tried printing a random element each time.

Comment: @Shashwat isn't there something like arr.pop()? Saw it somewhere in a YT tutuorial

Comment: @BramwellSimpson I guess you are confusing `Collections` with `arrays`. `Arrays` don't have any such method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do :

```
 String[] datas = new String[3];
 Random rand = new Random();
 rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

 int i = rand.nextInt(datas.length);
 String val = datas[i];
 datas[i] = null;
 return val;
```

Comment: Great answer, given +1 for that :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't delete the value per se, it just overwrites it with `null`. So the next time you randomly get that index, you'll end up with a `null` value.

Comment: 'tis alright, I'll just add the necessary error-checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use % operator to create a random index in the array.Use Math.random to get a fractional random number and use it to create the random index as follows

```
String[] arr = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse"};
    int randPos = ((int)(Math.random()*1000))%arr.length;
    String randEl = arr[randPos];
    System.out.println(randEl);
```

You cannot delete an element of array. All you can do is set it to null

Answer (score 0):

**To get a String** :

```
Random r = new Random();
String arr[3] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse"};
String selectedString = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
```

**For return, return the** *String* `selectedString` **from within a method**.

**To Delete**

```
Random r = new Random();
String arr[3] = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse"};
arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)] = null
```

**Note** that this won't shift the `array` elements, nor will the `array` be decreased in length.

If You need that kind of functionality, I suggest using a `Collection` like **Arraylist**

Answer (score 0):

You basically cannot delete an element from an array.

Follow the following steps:

1. **Convert your array to an ArrayList**

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));`

2. **Get a tandom number for index**

`int randPos = ((int)(Math.random()*1000))%arr.length;`

3. **Delete the element at that index**

`list.remove(randPos);`

4. **Convert it back to array of strings**

`arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);`

Hope this helps :)